# Failed to save double Value in NSUSerDefault

Tags: ios, objective-c, double, nsuserdefaults

Hi everybody :) i want to save a double Value into NSUserDefault like this:

```
NSUserDefaults *startValues = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

[startValues setDouble:[[self.dataList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]doubleValue] forKey:@"lat"];

[startValues synchronize];
```

I get no Errors or Warnings from Xcode, but when i run the Code, it crashes with the Message:

```
-[__NSCFDictionary doubleValue]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

I also tried to split up the Code like:

```
double lat = [[self.dataList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]doubleValue];

    [startValues setDouble:lat forKey:@"lat"];
```

but of course, i get the same error. Whats the Problem?

Thanks for your time and help :)

Comment: show us self.dataList data?

Comment: If you breakup the statement into it's several components, one to a line with intermediate vars you will be able to better see where the error is. IN this case that `[self.dataList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]` is a dictionary.

Comment: You are trying to convert NSDictionary object to double,
get value for 'lat' and then convert it to double

Comment: Use the debugger to see the intermediate values and/or `NSLog` statements for some caveman debugging.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `[self.dataList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]` contains a dictionary. NSDictionary does not understand the `doubleValue` message.

You have to somehow extract the double value from the dictionary:

```
NSDictionary *dictionary = self.dataList[indexPath.row];
double value = [dictionary[@"latitude"] doubleValue];
[startValues setDouble:value forKey:@"lat"];
```